# Cannot save Post

Tags: admin

I recently upgraded to 3.9.1 and cannot Save a draft, nor publish.  I have the draft written, click Save Draft and nothing happens other than the spinning icon next to the button.

I have disabled all plugins with no difference.  I have re-installed 3.9.1 to no avail.   If I pull up Chrome Developer tools I see the request go out, but it just stays in a 'pending' state with no return at all from the server.

Has anyone seen this behavior, if so how do I remediatie it?

Comment: Check your PHP error logs, maybe they can reveal something about this behaviour?

Comment: Also, I just spun up a vanilla install on Azure, and I can add a new post, and I can edit that post, but when I paste the text of my other post in, I get continuous spin.  It must be something in the content throwing an error on the post.php